# DataTable - InCell Editing How to get the Value of the object edited in the Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to get the row as object in My managed bean with its updated properties. I used the PrimeFaces showcase example [DataTable - InCell Editing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf). I don't understand how to get the edited values to update the database. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add a save button to the same form. E.g.

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{bean.save}" />
```

with

```
public void save() {
    someService.save(someList);
}
```

Or, if you want to perform the save on every individual row edit event, then add a `<p:ajax event="rowEdit">` to the `<p:dataTable>`. E.g.

```
<p:dataTable ...>
    ...
    <p:column>
        <p:rowEditor />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{bean.save}" />
</p:dataTable>
```

with

```
public void save(RowEditEvent event) {
    someService.save((SomeItem) event.getObject());
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the same and got an exception Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.buddhiedge.server.bean.EditBean@57e0d5.Save(org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent) My Save method in the managed bean is pasted below.public void save(RowEditEvent event) {
  setSelectedSubStudyPlan((StudyplanCategory)event.getObject());
  System.out.println("Hello............"+selectedSubStudyPlan.getName());
 } Please check whether the RowEdit event is of type org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent

Comment: Java is case sensitive. "Save" is not the same as "save".

Comment: <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{giftController.save(rowEdit)}" update="@form" /> What is the event in that context? My event is always null when pressed submit in save(RowEditEvent event).

Comment: @Sami: Remove `(rowEdit)`, exactly as shown in my answer. PrimeFaces will supply it itself.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't believe it :) Now I've got a problem with messages: <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{giftController.save}" update="@_this, :form:messagePanel:messages". I have tried just @_form, just @_this, just messages, :messages etc. I am using primefaces full layout and how I can get messages to come visible with AJAX? Undescores are just because of this forum :), it thinks that they are users...

Comment: Please press the `Ask Question` button and don't abuse comments to ask new questions.